# WiFi connected to router, but no internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet-connection, intel-wireless

I just got a new notebook, a ThinkPad Edge E530, and installed Ubuntu on it. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. On the same laptop, running Windows 7, the Wi-Fi connection works fine. Ethernet connection works both on Win7 and on Ubuntu. Only Wi-Fi on Ubuntu does not work; it connects to the Wi-Fi access point but I don't have Internet access.

My wireless card is Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230. 
What can fix the problem?

EDIT:

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:30:72:34  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:43 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:10124 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:10124 (10.1 KB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:15:e0:ec:01:00  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:5d:43:43:71:e1  
      inet addr:192.168.2.101  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6a5d:43ff:fe43:71e1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2801 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:26230 (26.2 KB)

route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0

cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SATELITE"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1F:1F:8D:CC:08   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:93  Invalid misc:243   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: We need a little more info. Could you show us the info for: # ifconfig -a # route -n # cat /etc/resolv.conf Based on these commands I will know more about the network configuration of the Notebook while it is connected.

Comment: Is this a personal wi-fi router, or is it a router you need to authenticate to use?  Sometimes you can authenticate to an access point so it looks like you're connected, but if the router hasn't authenticated you, you won't be able to route traffic through it... (Knowing what type of connection security you use in Windows 7 can help resolve this question.)

Comment: It's password protected WEP2. But somehow it was working for about 2 hours, and then suddenly it stopped working again. I dont know whats going on. Everyone says linux is better then windows but I have only problems with it ;/ It's my third day of configuring linux, I can't work.

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite sure what to ask next.  Hopefully someone else picks this question up...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a problem with power management in the driver.

Try disabling and re-enabling wireless using the network indicator. Also try connecting the laptop to power.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1038373

Look at other bug reports related to your driver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux?field.searchtext=iwlwifi